# Conditional checks across database fields

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I have a database "results" table with the following fields:

game_id,
home_team,
away_team,
home_team_score,
away_team_score,
result

Currently the result field has a possibility of 3 values, "H" (home team win), "A" (away team win) or "D" (draw). Now at the moment to get all the results for a particular team I do a query like "SELECT * FROM results where home_team = "TEAM A" or away_team = "TEAM A". And then inside my code I have to check to see if home_team is TEAM A and result is H then that's a win, draw or loss etc. Is there a way I can do this check in the query so I would get a list of results that's similar to below

game_id,
home_team,
away_team,
home_team_score,
away_team_score,
outcome (either W (win), L (lose) or D (draw))

based on the team that's queried.

Any help appreciated as struggled for resources on the web.

For reference it's a SQLite database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `case` to calculate the outcome in SQL:

```
select  *
,       case 
        when result = 'D' then 'D'
        when home_team = @YourTeam and result = 'H' then 'W'
        when away_team = @YourTeam and result = 'A' then 'W'
        else 'L'
        end as Outcome
from    YourTable
where   home_ream = @YourTeam
        or away_team = @YourTeam
```

Comment: The results are enumerated as `D,A,H`, not `D,W,L` ;)  Also, more importantly, if the away team has won, this will show a loss.

Answer (score 1):

A slight change to @Andomar's answer :)

```
SELECT
  *,
  CASE
    WHEN result = 'D'                             THEN 'Draw'
    WHEN home_team = @yourTeam AND result = 'H'   THEN 'Home Win'
    WHEN home_team = @yourTeam AND result = 'A'   THEN 'Home Loss'
    WHEN result = 'H'                             THEN 'Away Loss'
    ELSE                                               'Away Win'
  END
FROM
  YourTable
WHERE
     home_team = @yourTeam
  OR away_team = @yourTeam
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify venue (whether home or away) but it seems desirable.

The union of the combinations of home/away and W/L//D are easy to generate and easy to read IMO:

```
CREATE VIEW YourView
(
 game_id, home_team, away_team, 
 venue, outcome
)
AS
SELECT game_id, 
       home_team AS your_team,               
       away_team AS opponent_team, 
       'H' AS venue, 'W' AS outcome
  FROM YourTable
 WHERE result = 'H'
UNION
SELECT game_id, 
       away_team AS your_team, 
       home_team AS opponent_team, 
       'A' AS venue, 'W' AS outcome
  FROM YourTable
 WHERE result = 'A'
UNION
SELECT game_id, 
       home_team AS your_team, 
       away_team AS opponent_team, 
       'H' AS venue, 'L' AS outcome
  FROM YourTable
 WHERE result = 'A'
UNION
SELECT game_id, 
       away_team AS your_team, 
       home_team AS opponent_team, 
       'A' AS venue, 'L' AS outcome
  FROM YourTable
 WHERE result = 'H'
UNION
SELECT game_id, 
       home_team AS your_team, 
       away_team AS opponent_team, 
       'H' AS venue, 'D' AS outcome
  FROM YourTable
 WHERE result = 'D'
UNION
SELECT game_id, 
       away_team AS your_team, 
       home_team AS opponent_team, 
       'A' AS venue, 'D' AS outcome
  FROM YourTable
 WHERE result = 'A';

 SELECT * 
   FROM YourView
  WHERE your_team = @your_team;
```